# Hardware timer in C on Windows

Tags: c, timer, hardware

How to implement hardware timer on OS Windows. I need to measure computations in milliseconds and nanoseconds.

```
for (i=0;i<1024;i++){
  //start timer
  //computations
  //end timer
  //printf result(end - start)
}
```

Comment: Use getrusage() see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869470/set-time-t-to-miliseconds/52874744#52874744

Comment: I don't think you will be able to measure exact nanosecond values on a Windows machine.

Comment: A general-purpose desktop OS like Windows is inappropriate for such measurements.  To start with, you need a free hardware timer peripheral and a suitable driver for it.  That alone will screw up nanosecond accuracy, as will higher-priority interrupts.

Comment: In addition to Windows being desktop fluff, you will need very specialized hardware to get nanosecond accuracy. So running off to get a generic MCU evaluation board won't do either.

Comment: He said Windows. I was absent-minded.!

Comment: get the API for mouse movement. There should be a millisecond wait and reply

Answer (score 1):

Try using [QueryPerformanceFrequency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905(v=vs.85).aspx) and [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx) methods to obtain time in sub millisecond resolution:

```
LARGE_INTEGER cpu_khz, start_time, end_time;  
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&cpu_khz);
for (i=0;i<1024;i++) {
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&start_time); 
  // computations
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&end_time); 
  double delta_time = (start_time.QuadPart-end_time.QuadPart) / (double)cpu_khz.QuadPart;
  printf("took %.3f seconds", delta_time);
}
```